# PHP: <pre> tag not working with print_r

Tags: php, html, tags, pre

I've two code snippets. In first code snippet the `<pre></pre>` tag doesn't work while in second it works. Why so? Where I'm making a mistake in first code snippet?

**Code Snippet 1 Here it doesn't work**

```
      <?php
        $arr1 = array(2, 3);
        $arr2 = $arr1;
        $arr2[] = 4; // $arr2 is changed,
                     // $arr1 is still array(2, 3)

        $arr3 = &$arr1;
        $arr3[] = 4; // now $arr1 and $arr3 are the same

        echo "arr1 : "."<pre>".print_r($arr1)."</pre><br>";
        echo "arr2 : "."<pre>".print_r($arr2)."</pre><br>";
        echo "arr3 : "."<pre>".print_r($arr3)."</pre><br>"; 
    ?>
```

**Code Snippet 2 Here it works**

```
    <?php
      if ($_POST) {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_POST, true));
        echo '</pre>';
      }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Name:  <input type="text" name="personal[name]" /><br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="personal[email]" /><br />
        Beer: <br />
        <select multiple name="beer[]">
            <option value="warthog">Warthog</option>
            <option value="guinness">Guinness</option>
            <option value="stuttgarter">Stuttgarter Schwabenbräu</option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit me!" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are concatenating `pre` tag with output of `print_r`, So your code is first printing array and then concatenation.

**Note:**  You should pass `2nd` argument `true` for getting string output in return.

**Change this way to:**

```
echo "arr1 : <pre>".print_r($arr1)."</pre><br>";
```

**This:**

```
echo "arr1 : <pre>".print_r($arr1,true)."</pre><br>";
```

**OR**

```
echo "arr1 : <pre>";
print_r($arr1);
echo "</pre><br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me. I did that just to use single line of code instead of  adding multiple lines of code. Ultimately, the purpose of echo and print_r() is to generate the output only. I still didn't understand why my code didn't work out. Can't the output of print_r() be connected to anything like echo or something else? Please explain.